# How to create a dynamically sized column of a repeating string and add it simultaneously to the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of files with different user ids - the user ids don't appear inside these files. I want to open them, extract the timestamp and activity and at the same time create a new column - userid - whose userid members repeat themselves with the same frequency as the time stamps (for instance: if uid1 has 13 timestamps & activities, I want "uid1" to appear in the UID column 13 times as well followed by the uids and corresponding data from the next Uid file).

So in a nutshell, I want to create, size and append a column full of the respective UID element - how can I create such a dynamically sized column of repeated UID strings in Pandas and add it to the dataframe

Here is what I have attempted:

```
uidD = ['u02' 'u17' 'u18' 'u23' 'u31' 'u33' 'u46' 'u52' 'u16' 'u53']

for item in uidD: 
    files = glob.glob("Desktop/dataset/dataset/sensing/activity/activity_"+item+ ".csv")
    print(files)
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in files]
    lenDF = len(dfs[0])
    print(lenDF)
    print(type(dfs))
    uid = item * lenDF
    //dfs1 = dfs + uid 

    print(dfs)

    salesdata = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

and here is my dataset & what I printed from my code:

```
['Desktop/dataset/dataset/sensing/activity/activity_u02.csv']
527519
<class 'list'>
[                                    0
0       timestamp, activity inference
1                        1364356908,0
2                        1364356911,0
3                        1364356914,0
4                        1364356916,0
5                        1364356919,0
6                        1364356921,0
7                        1364356924,0
8                        1364356926,0
9                        1364356929,0
10                       1364356932,0
11                       1364356934,0
12                       1364356937,0
13                       1364356939,0
14                       1364356942,0
15                       1364356944,0
16                       1364356947,0
17                       1364356950,0
18                       1364356952,0
19                       1364356955,0
20                       1364356957,0
21                       1364356960,0
22                       1364356963,0
23                       1364356965,0
24                       1364357148,0
25                       1364357151,0
26                       1364357153,0
27                       1364357156,0
28                       1364357158,0
29                       1364357161,0
...                               ...
527489                   1370057886,0
527490                   1370057889,0
527491                   1370057892,0
527492                   1370057894,0
527493                   1370057897,0
527494                   1370057899,0
527495                   1370058082,0
527496                   1370058085,0
527497                   1370058087,0
527498                   1370058090,0
527499                   1370058093,0
527500                   1370058095,0
527501                   1370058098,0
527502                   1370058100,0
527503                   1370058103,0
527504                   1370058105,0
527505                   1370058108,0
527506                   1370058111,0
527507                   1370058113,0
527508                   1370058116,0
527509                   1370058118,0
527510                   1370058121,0
527511                   1370058123,0
527512                   1370058126,0
527513                   1370058129,0
527514                   1370058131,0
527515                   1370058134,0
527516                   1370058136,0
527517                   1370058139,0
527518                   1370058142,0
```

Comment: simply `for df in dfs: df['uidD'] = item`?

Comment: Actually, you can do even better with `saledata['uidD']=item`.

Comment: That works too! Thank you very much.But when I do pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index = True), only the last file being stored into data frame instead of all the files. Can you help me to fix that as well? Thank you.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dataFrames = []

for item in uidD: 
    files = glob.glob("Desktop/dataset/dataset/sensing/activity/activity_"+item+ ".csv")
    for filename in files:
        dfs = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        dfs["uid"] = item
        dataFrames.append(dfs)

salesdata = pd.concat(dataFrames, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```